# How to avoid code duplication in these functions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I tried to create a function template that would call a member function in an object, specified by the template parameter, but I failed. Now I have multiple functions that differ only very slightly:

```
static void resize_callback(raw_resource* ptr, int width, int height)
{
    owner* instance = static_cast<owner*>(get_owner(ptr));
    assert(instance != nullptr);
    instance->on_resize(width, height);
} 
static void focus_callback(raw_resource* ptr, bool state)
{
    owner* instance = static_cast<owner*>(get_owner(ptr));
    assert(instance != nullptr);
    instance->on_focus(state);
} 
static void other_callback(raw_resource* ptr, type1 arg1, type2 arg2, type3 arg3)
{
    owner* instance = static_cast<owner*>(get_owner(ptr));
    assert(instance != nullptr);
    instance->on_other(arg1, arg2, arg3);
} 
...
```

Each `raw_resource` has exactly one `owner`, where `owner` is a wrapper around `raw_resource`. The callbacks are fed to a low level C library that doesn't know about `owner`s, but only about `raw_resource`s, so they must take a `raw_resource*`, that a pointer to them (callbacks) has the appropriate type. The operations in the callbacks need to use the `owner` objects however, so they retrieve them through `get_owner()`.

How could I make a general function template out of these that would avoid code duplication? **I need instantiations of this template to be convertible to appropriate function pointers** that will be compatible with their current signatures, so they can be given to the low level C library.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

Comment: Can you tag with which version of C++ you have available?

Comment: If you could explain the relationship between `raw_resource`, `owner` and `window` it would help. `get_owner` returns something from a `raw_resource*` that you cast to a `window*` and store in an `owner*` so it's clearly not an `òwner*` already, so what is it?

Comment: Couple options I can think of out there, but please expand on **convertible to appropriate function pointers**.  What are these appropriate function pointers?

Comment: It seems odd that a function named `get_owner` returns a pointer that has to be cast to a `window*` in order to be saved as an `owner*`.

Comment: I noticed that the casting now has changed so the return value from `get_owner` is cast to an `owner*`. Still confusing. What is the relationship between these classes?

Comment: @TedLyngmo each `raw_resource` has exactly one `owner`, where `owner` is a wrapper around `raw_resource`. The callbacks are fed to a low level library that doesn't know about `owner`s, but only about `raw_resource`s, so they must take a `raw_resource*`, that a pointer to them (callbacks) has the appropriate type. The operations in the callbacks need to use the `owner` objects however, so they retrieve them through `get_owner`.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, but if you just show that relationship in code, it'll benefit everyone trying to answer. It *is* possible to answer anyway (as shown by @Sombrero and @Vlad)  but perhaps the answer will be better suited to your situation if we got the full picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a parameter pack:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Types>
static void callback(raw_resource* ptr, Func func, Types... args)
{
    owner* instance = static_cast<window*>(get_owner(ptr));
    assert(instance != nullptr);
    (instance->*func)(args...);
}
```

You might want to pass `Types` differently.

Used like:

```
callback(someptr, &owner::on_resize, width, height);
```

If you have C++17 available you could use `std::invoke` instead of the `->*` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As the number of arguments in each member function call is different then you can use the following approach

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    static void swap( int *x, int *y )
    { 
        int tmp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = tmp;
    }

    void set( bool b )
    {
        this->b = b;
    }

    bool b;
};

template <typename ...Args>
void operation( A *ptr, Args ... args )
{
    if constexpr( sizeof...( args ) == 1 )
    {
        ptr->set( args... );
    }
    else if constexpr( sizeof...( args ) == 2 )
    {
        ptr->swap( args... );
    }            
}

int main()
{
    A a = { false };

    operation( &a, true );

    std::cout << "a.b = " << a.b << '\n';

    int x = 10; int y = 20;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << '\n';

    operation( &a, &x, &y );

    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
a.b = 1
x = 10, y = 20
x = 20, y = 10
```